# groupby to get the average, using dynamic condition

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have been searching about groupby using conditions and found many posts about that. This one for example: [Pandas: conditional group-specific computations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250832/pandas-conditional-group-specific-computations)

However, I couldn't find any where the condition is applied over itself. In my case I'd like to get the average (or count or any other formula for that matter) but the thing that I couldn't find is to filter the dataset over a dynamic condition.

To illustrate this, this is the summarized dataset:

```
ID | Seq | Total 
1  | 1   | 1
1  | 2   | 2
1  | 3   | 3
2  | 1   | 1
2  | 2   | 2
2  | 3   | 1
```

If I want to get the mean grouped by ID, but with the additional condition that for each record within the group, only those where the Seq is smaller must be computed. This should be the result

```
ID | Seq | Total | x
1  | 1   | 1     | 1 <-- mean of 1
1  | 2   | 2     | 1.5 <-- mean of 1 and 2
1  | 3   | 3     | 2 <-- mean of 1,2 and 3
2  | 1   | 1     | 1 <-- mean of 1
2  | 2   | 2     | 1.5 <-- mean of 1 and 2
2  | 3   | 1     | 1.33  < mean of 1, 2 and 1
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding what you are looking to achieve. How are you computing `Total` in the 2 examples?

Comment: Sorry, I have just corrected it. Total is a given value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are just trying to get the `expanding().mean()` of the `ID`-grouped `Total` column, e.g.:

```
In []:
df['x'] = df.groupby('ID')['Total'].expanding().mean().values
df

Out[]:
   ID  Seq  Total         x
0   1    1      1  1.000000
1   1    2      2  1.500000
2   1    3      3  2.000000
3   2    1      1  1.000000
4   2    2      2  1.500000
5   2    3      1  1.333333
```

Comment: Wow, I thought that Seq should be included so that only values of seq smallers are included in the calculation of the mean. Why in your code only the previous values are calculated rather than the full ID group? Thanks again

Comment: `groupby()` already chunks up the data, `expanding()` provides an expanding window on the group which you are looking for the `mean()`.

Comment: Might be worth emphasizing that you need Seq to be ordered (so the expanding works), and ID to be ordered (otherwise dropping to `.values` could get you into trouble as we aren't using sort=False).

Comment: @DSM Good point, it assumes `ID` is ordered. Not sure why you believe `Seq` has to be ordered - it is never referenced.

Comment: @AChampion: er, because Seq is pretty obviously specifying the sequence order of elements within a group, and if those are shuffled the resulting expanding mean will be different, precisely _because_ Seq is never explicitly referenced.

Comment: @DSM, sorry, yes already assumed based on the data provided. Out of order data, could be pre-sorted before calling `groupby()`.